# GWT Element.getAbsoluteLeft and getAbsoluteTop gives very large value when zoomed in to 99%

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt

I have an application developed using GWT 2.3. The getAbsoluteLeft() and getAbsoluteTop() methods are used to get left and top position of textbox as given below.The correct values are return in IE11 in normal screen (zoom=100% or more). But if we zoom in the screen to 99% or below it returns a very large value.

```
int left=textbox.getAbsoluteLeft();
int top= textbox.getAbsoluteTop();
```

**Values returned when screen is zoomed in to 99% or less**

```
left = 2147483647
top = -2147483649
```

The value returned is the min and max range if int. What is the correct way to get absolute left and top position here. Is there any alternate method in GWT to get this done correctly in IE11?

It works fine in IE8 with normal and any value of zoom percent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help...

But try :

```
private static native double getElementLeft(Element element)
/*-{
   var rectObject = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   return rectObject.left;
}-*/;

private static native double getElementTop(Element element)
/*-{
   var rectObject = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   return rectObject.top;
}-*/;
```

This uses getBoundingClientRect (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) which I know is not used by the GWT code getAbsoluteLeft and getAbsoluteTop.
The plus of using getBoundingClientRect is that it gives subPixel values (doubles instead of ints), which is sometimes needed.